# How to set the background colour of individual gridview cells

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView with each cell containing some text, and I want to be able to set the background colour of individual cells.

The XML for my GridView is:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/students_grid"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:numColumns="6"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
</GridView>
```

The code for my GridView is:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.students_grid);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, student_array);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I had hoped I would be able to set the background colour of individual cells using:

```
gridView.getChildAt(random_student).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18A608"));
```

However, this throws a null pointer exception, and on further examination it seems that gridview.getChildCount() returns 0. I have seen that gridview.getCount returns the number of items in the gridview correctly, but this doesn't help me to set the background colour of individual cells.

Any ideas where I go next?

Answer (score 10):

The key to solving this problem is to first understand how `ListView` and `GridView` work. `GridView` creates and destroys child views as you scroll up and down. If you can't see an item in a `GridView` that means there is no child view for it, it will be created when the user actually scrolls to it. `GridView` uses an `Adapter` to create the views and `GridView` recycles views when they go offscreen and asks the Adapter to reuse the recycled views for new views that come on screen. The `Adapter` usually inflates a resource layout to create new views.

So what this means is that `GridView` will call `getView(...)` on the `Adapter` each time it wants to display a child view on screen, it may pass a recycled View called `convertView`.

The solution is to override `getView(...)`, call super to let the `Adapter` create and populate the view with data from the `String` array normally but add a bit of code at the end before we give the view back to `GridView` that sets the color of the view.

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, student_array) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    int color = 0x00FFFFFF; // Transparent
    if (someCondition) {
      color = 0xFF0000FF; // Opaque Blue
    }

    view.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return view;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

**Main activity where you have to create array of hexadecimal color code and and pass to custom adapter class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GridView gridView;


    String[] gridColor ={

            "#008B8B",
            "#00FF00",
            "#48D1CC",
            "#556B2F",
            "#696969",
            "#6B8E23",
            "#8FBC8F",
            "#AFEEEE",
            "#B8860B",
            "#BDB76B",
            "#D8BFD8",
            "#DEB887",
            "#FFFF00",
            "#FFF0F5",
            "#EE82EE",
            "#DC143C",
            "#C0C0C0"
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Grid adapter = new Grid(MainActivity.this,gridColor);
        gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked On " +gridcolor[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

*In custom adapter code will be like this where color code will be parsed*

```
public class Grid extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] menu;
    private final int[] Imageid;
    private final String[] gridcolor;

    public Grid(Context context,String[] menu,int[] Imageid,String[] gridcolor)
    {
        mContext=context;

        this.gridcolor=gridcolor;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return gridcolor.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (view == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);

            grid.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(gridcolor[i]));

        } else
        {
            grid =  view;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a custom layout and use it in your adapter instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. For example:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:background="#18A608"
     />
```

(I simply copied the latest version of `simple_list_item_1.xml` and added the new background color at the end.)

Save this as `grid_layout.xml` in `res/layout` and change your adapter's constructor to:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.grid_layout, student_array);
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for initialising all of the cells when the screen is created.

But I also need to access and change cells dynamically. Is there a way to reference individual cells at runtime in order to change their colour?

Comment: (Sorry, I just found your response.) Yes, but do you want to highlight just one cell or every cell that matches a criteria (like every third cell or every student that is failing)?

Comment: @Mark__C yes, override BaseAdapter as suggested in the SDK.