# How to set background resource for only gridview selected item in android?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to set Background resource of selected item in gridview. When I select an item, it's ok, but the program is not change background resource of only selected item. It changes another item's background too. I can not solve this problem. I have researched, but I couldn't find my problem's solution. Here is my code:

```
grid_similar_items.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid_similar_items.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
           View v = grid_similar_items.getChildAt(i);
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        }
grid_similar_items.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_item_bg_color);
}
```

Note: I have a year list of items for example: 2012 - 2013 - 2014 and assume that there are 8 items in 2012, 52 items in 2013, and 52 items in 2014. in short gridview list(2012), I did not faced this problem. However, in large gridview list(2013 and 2014) I have faced this problem.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you implement holder in adapter? Using holder will prevent the views to re-inflate. I think thats the source of your problem.

Comment: I have done it. Actually, I tried to solve using selector.xml but I learnt that selector is not true solution because it does not support keep changed background constantly. So, I tried this way. I can show my adapter getView method:

Comment: how can I implement holder in my adapter ? Are there any instance for it do you have ?

Comment: Check this 8. ListViews and performance in the link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html to implement holder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Way is to create custom adapter class which return view of your choose, or you can use this link [gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885903/how-to-set-the-background-colour-of-individual-gridview-cells)